# Angular Date Filter not filtering in ng-value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
// date = 2015-12-05T02:34:45.249Z
<div>
  <p>{{date | date:'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</p> // This works, shows the correct date
</div>

<label>
  <input type="date" ng-value="{{date | date:'yyyy/MM/dd'}}"> // This doesn't work
</label>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEGLWL)

I'm not sure what is going on. The first filter works well, but the second one doesn't format the date at all, leaving the date as the initial string.

Comment: Remember, when you use the "ng-*" attribute in HTML, you should never use angular brackets around its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<label>
    <input type="date" ng-value="date | date:'yyyy/MM/dd'">
</label>
```

This will show the correct date format in your structure

Answer (score 1):

Well this works for me

```
<input type="text" placeholder="DOB" ng-value="dataValue | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'">
```

if you give type "date" then it will hide place  holder so better to pass it as text.

Answer (score 0):

When you do what Soluciones Intuitivas wrote and change type from date to text you will see date. If you want to use `type="date"` you should add directive to convert data to correct format.
Directive should return something like:

```
return new Date(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use input `type='text'`. Then you could use the date as this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{date | date:'yyyy/MM/dd'}}">
```

This way (using `type='text'`) you can control the actual date format displayed to the user, instead of allowing browser to select your locale's format (which is not what you always want)